Simpsons episode: military video with atomic bomb
I'm looking for an episode where a military video is shown.

The video shows an atomic bomb detonating in the background. In the foreground a soldier smiles and gives a thumbs up. Then his teeth and his thumb fall off.
I think the video is shown at the elementary school.
It must be an older episode (first 10 seasons, I guess).


... Yvan eht nioj?

@Steve-O Just watched the episode. The scene is not in there.

The episode is $pringfield (Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Legalized Gambling) from Season 5. The footage appears at the beginning of the episode and is being watched by Grampa Simpson and Jasper in a flashback. Here's a video:




A quick search of Simpsonsarchive.com turns up the episode Homer's Odyssey as a possible match:  https://www.simpsonsarchive.com/episodes/7G03.html 
In the ep, the kids go on a field trip to the power plant and watch a video on nuclear power, which includes an A-bomb explosion.  
*I won't be able to confirm this by checking the episode myself until at least this evening.

I just checked it. Unfortunately that video does not include any soldier.

@Torsten - thanks for checking, I wasn't able to get to it myself last night.
